# Accessing value of data tag in html5

Tags: html

How do I access the data tag value in my javascript?
Can I put data tag to my input elements?

For example, in this code:

```
<input name="demo"><data value="1234"> Demo </data>
```

How do I acccess this value?

Comment: "<input name="demo"><data value="1234"> Demo </data>" is the html

Comment: You can use 4 spaces before your code to make it visible as a code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html5, `data-*` can be added as an attribute.

You can add data in your `input` element like this ;

```
<input type=text" id="eltid" data-somedata="somevalue" >
```

and access it in javascript with :

```
var elt = document.getElementById('eltid');
var mydata = elt.dataset.somedata;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add data value in input box

```
<input value="1234" id="abc" name="demo" /> Demo
```

and call jascript

```
var lol = document.getElementById('abc').value;
alert(lol);
```